# str_replace_all on sentence based on dataframe using r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Sample sentence

```
sentence <-"Mr. Smith moved to San Francisco in December."
```

This is the extracted entity from spacyr package:

```
spacy_extract_entity(sentence)
```

[image]

and lookup list I want to assign my own hex code for the ent_type

```
ent_type <- c('PERSON', 'ORG', 'LOC',  'DATE')
hex      <- c('#336',  '#F3C', '#7F7', '#FF0')
```

How can I return the ent_type and hex value and replace in the sentence like this using str_replace_all:

```
Mr. Smith(PERSON)-#336 moved to San Francisco(LOC)-#7F7 in December(DATE)-#FF0.
```

Comment: I guess you need more data to train a model. What is a person? What is a location?...

Comment: Actually I have a sample sentence and I used spacyr package to extract the entity. what I want is to replace the ent_type and hex code in the sentence using str_replace_all function thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code to work you need to install this package first: `devtools::install_github("bmewing/mgsub")`.

I also use the `tibble` package to create the mockup dataframe you shared in your original post.

NB: `str_replace_all` from `stringr` won't work because it does not do multiple substitutions on the same string. For a nice discussion see: http://thug-r.life/post/2018-01-10-safe-multiple-string-substitutions/.

```r
# You need to install mgsub: devtools::install_github("bmewing/mgsub")

sentence <-"Mr. Smith moved to San Francisco in December."
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~text, ~ent_type,
  "Smith", "PERSON",
  "San Francisco", "LOC",
  "December", "DATE")

text2entity <- df$ent_type
names(text2entity) <- df$text

ent_type <- c('PERSON', 'ORG', 'LOC',  'DATE')
hex      <- c('#336',  '#F3C', '#7F7', '#FF0')

entity2hex <- sprintf("(%s)-%s", ent_type, hex)
names(entity2hex) <- ent_type

text2hex <- sprintf("%s%s", names(text2entity), entity2hex[df$ent_type])
names(text2hex) <- df$text

mgsub::mgsub(sentence,pattern=df$text,replacement=text2hex)
#> [1] "Mr. Smith(PERSON)-#336 moved to San Francisco(LOC)-#7F7 in December(DATE)-#FF0."
```

Comment: nice thanks.!! another question again how to apply in paste () function with HTML tag to get the hex code for font color and together with the text and ent_type. Example :paste0('<span style=\"background-color:', hex, '\ ">',text,' 
          #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;">',ent_type,'</span></span>')

Comment: I mean the replacement in mgsub will be html tag using paste0() like this: paste0('<span style=\"background-color:', hex, '\ ">',text,' #<span style=\"font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;">',ent_type,'</span></span>')

Comment: @bea: I am finding it hard to understand what is this next question of yours. But maybe post another question with this specific issue and I will try to help. Meanwhile if this answer did the job you may mark it as the right answer. :)